# Pipeline one argument to multiple functions?

Tags: f#

How can you pipeline one argument to multiple functions? For instance, if i wanted the tuple (2,5) to be passed to both `fst` and `snd` and then pass the result of each as two arguments to another function - this could be illustrated with the following hypothetical, non-working, code:
`(2,5) |> (fst & snd) |> addUp(nr1, nr2)`

Comment: Your question makes little sense to me. What you want to achieve in your hypothetical example can be achieved by pattern matching:

``let (a, b) = twoValues in addUp (a, b)``

Comment: "(2,5) |> addUp "

Comment: that answers the example...though not the question

Comment: I wonder if what you're thinking of is something like "lenses"...google it...it about transforming records

Answer (score 2):

The pipeline operator is useful for implementing what the name suggests - a *pipeline* where you need to pass some input through a series of transformations.

If you want a more complex flow of data, then you'll get much better results just by using the normal mechanism for passing data through a program that F# provides, i.e. variables:

```
let tuple = (2,5) 
let nr1 = fst tuple
let nr2 = snd tuple 
addUp nr1 nr2
```

If you happen to be working with tuples, you can also use pattern matching:

```
let tuple = (2,5) 
let nr1, nr2 = tuple
addUp nr1 nr2
```

You can invent combinators and operators like `|>` to do this without variables, but that defeats the purpose of the pipeline operator which is to make code more readable.

Comment: hmmmm.....I agree there is tension between readability and brevity....there is a point when you want to wave your hands and hide the plumbling...especially if that plumbing is everwhere (e.g. computational expressions are effectively a point free sugar on top of monads...we choose to hide the plumbing)

Answer (score 1):

So lets start with a better example...and guess what you're after

lets defined add like this...making it explicit that it operates on a 2 tuple...not curried.

```
let addUp : (int * int) -> int =
    fun (x,y) -> x + y
```

and you want to go (lets say)

```
let z = (2,4)|> (fun (x,y) -> 2*x,y) |> addUp
```

which is ugly.

but note we are create a pipeline that transforms 2 tuples, and then applying some function to it.

Now tuple is a "functor"...which means when we get a function that operates on a type inside the Tuple, we can transform (lift) it into a function that operates on the whole of the tuple.

2 Tuple is a functor twice over;

```
module TupleFst = 
    let map : ('a -> 'b) -> ('a * 'c) -> ('b * 'c) = 
        fun f (x,y) -> (f x, y)
module TupleSnd = 
    let map : ('a -> 'b) -> ('c * 'a) -> ('c * 'b) = 
        fun f (x,y) -> (x,f y)
```

I've defined them with the signatures to make it obvious whats going on.

In TupleFst, we take a function that operates on the first element of a tuple, and we "lift" that into a function that operates on the whole tuple (that maps the first element).

In TupleSnd, we do the second member of the tuple.

so we can now write the example as....

```
let z = (2,4)|> TupleFst.map ((*) 2) |> addUp
```

is that better?...debatable...in this trivial example it probably makes life worse, but the principle is there....if you look at FSharpPlus at functors and applicatives theres much more on it....and it can be applied to all sorts of data structures.

I think that package uses the same syntax sugar stolen from Haskell, where I think you can write the above as;

```
let z = ((*) 2) <!> (2,4) |> addUp
```

but I haven't installed it and got all that to work...so there may be a typo wrong in the above (ah...I'm not sure how to tell FSharpPlus which functor to choose "map" from...so the above is ambiguous and probably doesn't compile...you can of course define your own operator instead of "map")

```
let (<!>) = TupleFst.map
let (<!!>) = TupleSnd.map
let z1 = ((*) 2) <!> (2,4) |> addUp
let z2 = ((*) 2) <!!> (2,4) |> addUp
```

this does compile "!" operates on he 1st element in the tuple, "!!" on the second....(I'm not sure "!!" is a sensible name...whilst "!" is idiomatic..but whatever)

(in this case this is all complete overkill!...the other answers are better...I think I was trying to demonstrate that if you are working in a lifted world (here tuples), you can often hide the plumbling).

Answer (score 1):

```
(2, 5)
|> fun t -> first t, second t
||> addUp
```

The second line will pass the input tuple to both the `first` and `second` functions and return their combined result as a new tuple.

This is assuming that `addUp` takes two regular arguments (not a tuple). If it takes a tuple, instead use the regular pipe operator `|>` in the last line.

Complete example:

```
let first (a, b) = a * b
let second (a, b) = a ** b
let addUp a b = a + b

let answer =
    (2.0, 5.0)
    |> fun t -> first t, second t
    ||> addUp

// answer is 42.0
```

Comment: fun t -> first t, second t...is just the id function...it does nothing?

Comment: @MrD `first` and `second` are functions that take a tuple as an argument. The `fun t -> first t, second t` is a function that takes a tuple, calls `first` with that tuple, calls `second` with that same tuple, and returns the results from both those functions composed as a tuple.

Comment: @MrD Ah, I believe you're thinking of `fst` and `snd` which of course would make that line behave like `id`. I changed them to avoid that confusion, but I guess I didn't do a great job of that! :-)

Comment: ahha...I changed it to something more interesting in my answer...so I got the jist anyway...ie it doesnt really matter what the the function is...as long as its a pipeline operating on tuples, you can apply "Functor" logic to it

Comment: maybe I'll ammend my code to directly answer the question and see if it still works

Comment: actually your example doesnt really work in my world very easily without introducing all sorts of "noise"...so in this case I think your answer is better :-)